# Hive date column shows null while querying the data

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, apache-spark-sql, hql

Loaded data of spark data frame in hive table.
Before loading df.show(10) shows date column in proper format and data, but while querying hive table date column shows null.

```
//Spark Code
df.show(10)
+----------+
|    bus_dt|
+----------+
|2021-12-01|
+----------+

//Hive shell
select distinct bus_dt from stg.dateTable;
NULL

//Table
create table stg.dateTable (
`bus_dt` date comment 'from deserializer')
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '/u0003'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
TBLPROPERTIES (
'serialization.null.format'=''
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try changing the DDL to use serde rather than TxtInputFormat.

```
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.MultiDelimitSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ('field.delim'='/u0003')
TBLPROPERTIES('serialization.null.format'='');
```

The issue seems to be with storage and retrival at hive side rather than at spark processing.